# Unable to scroll down on html pages where div content extends below display

Tags: html, css

I've tried using overflow:auto or overflow:scroll to fix, and while it does add a scroll bar to the area needed, it still does not recognize when the page needs to have that functionality.

Here's my site link and css code:

http://mildsclan.com/newsite/index.html

http://mildsclan.com/newsite/styles/global.css

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Not able to understand your problem. if you are talking about the scroll on whole body just remove the overflow attribute from body class in css. IT will show scroll whenever content lenght more the the browser hieght

Answer (score 4):

remove `overflow:hidden` from your `body` styles.. to get this fixed

Answer (score 2):

try to add `height` and `overflow` in your class `content` . it will add scroll to only content dov

```
.content {
  width: auto;
  background-color: #95a5a5;

  margin-left: 250px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #424242 0%, #687080 50%, #95a5a5 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #424242 0%, #687080 50%, #95a5a5 100%);
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

if you want to scroll whole page with left side bar then remove `overflow` from body as jaw.sh suggested.

```
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';

}
```

Comment: For .content, he need the height like that : height: calc(100% - 53px);

Comment: yes . may be. because of the header. I am not so good in the css

Answer (score 0):

Remove the definition `overflow: hidden;` on your `body`.

As the name implies, this hides content that doesn't fit within its natural boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Your current HTML body tag has the following properties under CSS

```
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

removing or commenting out the overflow property will fix the issue

```
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok that makes sense. I think I originally added overflow:hidden to the body because without it, the left side navigation bar doesn't go to the bottom of the page. Basically I'm just looking to make everything 100% width/height unless text or images extent below the screen. Here's a screenshot of my portfolio page after I remove overflow:hidden:

http://screencast.com/t/6pR3MqdgQC